# Pass the ComboBox.SelectedText parameter to another class

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to pass the `.SelectedText` (preferably) or the `.SelectedItem` from a ComboBox on my main form DetailerReports to my logic class Math.cs. I've been working and searching for several hours now and I'm hoping someone will direct me further. I have been passing from Math to DetailerReport, but not the other way around so I thought it would be similar. I've tried several options though I think this is the closest but not currently functioning solution. I'm declaring the parameter publicly and trying to assign the value when the SelectedIndexChanged event is triggered for `cbSelectProject` comboBox

```
public partial class DetailerReports : Form
{
    public string cbSelectedProjectValue = "";

    public void cbSelectProject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbSelectedProjectValue == "")
        {
            cbSelectedProjectValue = cbSelectProject.SelectedText;

            MessageBox.Show(cbSelectedProjectValue);
        }

        //return cbSelectedProjectValue;
    }
}
```

I was hoping to return the value `cbSelectedProjectValue` and pass that to my `Math.cs` for use as a variable

```
string cbSelectProjectValue = DetailerReports.cbSelectProject_SelectedIndexChanged();
```

or

```
string cbSelectProjectValue = DetailerReport.cbSelectedProjectValue;
```

Neither of these is working. If anyone can please point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. Thank You in advance for your time and consideration. Have a Great Day!! :-D

Comment: You need instance of `DetailerReport`, then your approach will works as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to implement and instance of `DetailerReport`. Could you possibly expand on your answer? I would really appreciate it. Thank You for your response. :-D

Comment: I don't know what your Math.cs looks like but a few things can be done to provide this functionality.

You can opt to create a custom EventArgs class which encases the values that you need and pass it as an object.

Another option would be to extend your said Math.cs so that it can accept an object.

Another option would be to bind the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string cbSelectProjectValue = DetailerReports.cbSelectProject_SelectedIndexChanged();
```

This won't work since this is a public method (=cannot be access statically) and it is a method that is called by an event.

```
string cbSelectProjectValue = DetailerReports.cbSelectedProjectValue;
```

This also won't work since you cannot access this public variable statically.

If you like to exchange values, you can do that by changing the modifier to **static**, but this is not a quite good solution.

```
public static string cbSelectedProjectValue = "";
```

It would be better to exchange this value by parameters of methods. Such as

```
public void cbSelectProject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Math.doSomething(cbSelectProject.SelectedText);
}
```

where **Math.doSomething()** expects a string.

EDIT:

As you need to pass values between forms, it is a good idea to use the concept of a "controller". In the following implementation I used MyController to store two properties. Now, whenever a new Form is instanciated, the MyController reference is passed as a parameter and public variables of the MyController instance can be accessed from every Form.

**Program.cs**

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    //instanciate MyController for further use
    controller = new MyController();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new FormMain(controller));
}

private static MyController controller;
```

**MyController.cs**

```
public class MyController
{
    //store values here, which are needed accross various Forms
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

**FormMain.cs**

```
MyController controller;

public FormMain(MyController controller)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.controller = controller; //Assign the controller to have access to stored variables
}
private void btnStartSecondForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //access and get/set values here
    string importantValue = controller.A;
    controller.B = 1;

    FormSecond formSecond = new FormSecond(controller);
    formSecond.Show();
}
```

**FormSecond.cs**

```
MyController controller;

public FormSecond(MyController controller)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.controller = controller; //Same here

    //access values here that you have previously set in FormMain
    int valueFromOtherForm = controller.B;
}
```

Comment: I don't know that it is avoidable but I'm hoping to avoid this. My concern is that I will have to pass this string to `Math.doSomething` from other forms as well. FYI I'm building a small HR time tracking that will allow the user to access their time to create charts to help them. Of course the Supv wants to track everyones time, so the charts may be wild. I'm hoping to reuse `Math.doSomething()` for this purpose. Processing....

Comment: And THANK YOU very much for responding. I really really appreciate it. :-D

Comment: You're welcome! I edited my answer and added further code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you rogi1609. I had to do it backwards as suggested by the `Math.doSomething()`. I'll need to rework a bunch of code, but I think this will be the easiest work around for the way I prefer to work my code. I'm more of a step by step person, but it makes it easier for me to read. I don't work with a lot of huge DB's anyway. Programming is not my main job. Thanks Again!! :-D Have a Great Day

Comment: Hey rogi1609. Just read your edits. I'm not sure that this will work for me, but I'm not sure. Without closing the main form I fear I'll have a lot of junk running (not to worry some for RAM. We do a lot of graphics so we get pretty high end machines). Interested in your opinion though. The entire app is set up so that the main form is always accessible via modeless windows. Problem is if the child form closes, all other grand child forms must close. I'd have to `Dispose()` of `controller` by reaching through the parent form `MainForm` into `Program.cs` to `Dispose()` only `controller`?

Comment: You're welcome. You can easily achieve this by adding a `List<Form> forms` to every of your Form-classes. When starting a new form, add the form to the list beforehand and also override the `OnFormClosing` method inside the class where you call form.Close() of every form which is contained in the list. If you'd like to see the code, I can edit the answer.

Comment: Nah, it's all good :-D I gotta learn one step at a time. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you define public field/property/method like this

```
public partial class DetailerReports : Form
{
    public string SomeField = ""; // not recommended, better use properties
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public void SomeMethod(...) {...}
}
```

then you need *instance*

```
var form = new DetailerReport(); // somewhere you create instance of DetailerReport
form.ShowDialog();
```

to access them

```
DetailerReport.SomeField = "123"; // will not work
form.SomeField = "123"; // is ok
```

You will have to store that instance somewhere or pass it to `Math`. From your last comment it will be the best for you to create multiple instance of `Math` classes (per form), then `Math` can have constructor which accept that form instance.

In case of properties you can define them in `Math` as well, so that form (creating own instance of `Math`) will use it as a *holder* of data.

But in case of methods you are doomed to use interfaces. Each form has to implement that interface. Something like

```
public interface IBaseForm
{
    void SomeMethod1();
    void SomeMethod2(bool someParameter);
    string SomeProperty { get; set; } 
}

public class DetailerReport: Form, IBaseForm
{
    Math _math;

    public DetailerReport()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        _math = new Math(this);
    }

    // impolement IBaseForm
    public void SomeMethod1() { ... }
    ...
}

public class Math
{
    IBaseForm _form;
    public Math(IBaseForm form)
    {
        _form = form;
        // and then you can use call methods
        _form.SomeMethod1();
    }   
}
```